# Should the F-test statistic be rejected?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing, p-value

I have an f-value = $2.3$ and am trying to determine if I should reject the null at the $1\%$ level. Do I need to calculate the p-value to solve this question? What's the best way to get the p-value if I have the f-statistic, degrees of freedom, and the data points?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would probably to use R. You could find a critical value and then compare it to your f-statistic. If the f-statistic is greater than the critical value, you would reject the null at the $1\%$ level.

Other way is to calculate the p-value and if your p-value is less than $1\%$ then you would reject.

The commands are respectively `qf(.99, m, n)` and `pf(2.3, m, n)` with `m,n` the degrees of freedom for the F-distribution.

Note: the F-distribution is only one-sided.